# Is polling in a trigger supported in Zapier?

Tags: zapier

I am in the process of writing a zapier trigger in which I need to initiate our file download api, which in turn provides a url to poll, once I get a file ready status, I can construct a file download url.
Is it possible to have polling code in a trigger?
Are there any size limits on the files that zapier supports?
Once I have my download url, can simply use this code?

```
return _.map(records, function(record) {
  // if you just do url, we'll include any standard authentication headers
  record.file = z.dehydrateFile('//mysite.com/mypath/download' + record.id);
  return record;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

David here, from the Zapier Platform team.

You can do basically whatever you want in a trigger, but there's a couple of important things to keep in mind:

- The goal is to fetch a lot of items, return them all, and zapier zapier decide which ones are new
- you've got 30 seconds total for the trigger, so if you're polling for lots of results, you're going to timeout
- there's a very important [line in the docs](https://github.com/zapier/zapier-platform-cli#stashing-files):

> Note: you should only be using z.stashFile() in a hydration method or a hook trigger's perform if you're sending over a short-lived URL to a file. Otherwise, it can be very expensive to stash dozens of files in a polling call

The worst case scenario here is that every time we poll (which happens every 5-15 minutes), you wait for a file for each result and stash it every time (without knowing if the user needs it or not).

You should follow the example in the docs, where during the Zapier poll, you dehydrate your polling operation. When we decide an item is new, we'll do that poll, stash the file once it's ready, and send it to the user appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

Polling should be generally avoided as it causes performance issues. If you can, you may want to write your polling code in a background function (see `serverless` functions) or background code. It does the heavy-lifting for you. Create a Zapier `Webhook`. From the background code/function, do an HTTP `POST` of your file/data one-by-one (as if a **new item created/updated**) to the `Webhook`. This structure/architecture makes your trigger. With your use case above, you can send just the download url to `Webhook`. After that, you can add a `zap` to use this trigger and consume the incoming data and send to an `action`. This makes it cleaner and efficient.

Ref: [Webhooks](https://zapier.com/apps/webhook/integrations)

Comment: Thank you Prasad, looks like this will solve my problem, I will explore it and update.